# Trying The Multiple Assignment Trick but it doesn't work in python terminal?

Tags: python, list, printing, terminal

I was reading automating python and was reading about The Multiple Assignment Trick so I decided to try it out in the terminal. Made an empty list and try to update with it but it doesn't work at least not when I print out the list again.

```
>>>> cat = ['fat', 'orange', 'loud']
>>>> print(cat)
>>>> ['fat', 'orange', 'loud']
>>>> size, color, disposition = cat
>>>> print(cat)
>>>> ['fat', 'orange', 'loud']
```

At this point I thought line 4 would update the values in list 'cat' but it doesn't when I print it out. If I type

```
>>>> size in cat
True
```

If I type 'orange in cat' I get `NameError: name orange is not defined`, is there any reason why I don't see value updated when I print out the new list?

Comment: What is it that you think this code should accomplish?

Comment: Either way, I get the feeling that you should be carefully reviewing a tutorial (like the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/index.html)) before trying "tricks."

Comment: Where have you defined orange? Also how would anything in your snippet change the list content?

Comment: Why do you think line 4 would change `cat`?  Line 4 "reads" the 3 values in `cat` and copies them to `size`, `color`, & `disposition`.

Comment: If you had reviewed this tutorial, you might have realized that you were confusing strings and variables, so it looks like my advice was actually helpful. Please do review your instructional materials before asking a question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `orange in cat`, you get `NameError` because `orange` is not a variable. You need to do:

```
'orange' in cat  # check as string
```

OR

```
color in cat  # check with variable storing 'orange'
```

because `color` variable is storing the value of orange. (Similar to what you are doing with `size` in the question)

Comment: Thanks my friend, I didn't know why my brain farted so bad. Can't believe I got string and variable mixed. I understand now thanks again!